# How much resistance to drop voltage from 18 v to 12 v dc?

Tags: power-supply, led, resistors, dc-motor, 12v

I am going to make a electronic model for my project. I need to drop voltage from 18 v to 12 v for running a 12v dc motor.

- So how much *resistor* i need?
- May i use leds in *series* to drop voltage ? How many leds?
  **Would using leds instead of resistor reduce the motor performance?**

Comment: None of the above. Use a proper voltage regulator.

Comment: Voltage regulator use not allowded in my project

Comment: _Why_ is a voltage regulator not allowed?

Comment: The project belongs to a lower class student

Comment: **It is impossible to answer your question**, because --for one thing-- you haven't told us how much current the motor draws.

Comment: A 1 ohm resistor will drop 6v if you're drawing 6 amps. A 1Mohm resistor will drop six volts if you're drawing 6uA. As you see, any specific value of resistor will not meet your spec if the current drawn varies, like the current a motor draws as the load varies for instance.

Comment: It is No-load current = 60 mA(Max), Max Load current = 300 mA(Max)"

Comment: V = I * R. V = 6, I is the current going through the resistor, solve for R.

Comment: 9 or 10 silicon diodes in series would work - with current rating greater than the PSU and motor. But not resistors, and not LEDs.  But really you want a regulator (or a buck convertor) or to get the correct supply in the first place.

Comment: You can use a Zener diode like 1N5340B: 6.0 V, 5.0 W in series.

Comment: You basically never want to put a resistor in series with a motor.

Comment: "No-load current = 60 mA(Max), Max Load current = 300 mA(Max)" - is it like this motor? http://robokitsworld.com/motors/500rpm-12v-dc-motor-with-gearbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using a resistor is that its voltage drop varies depending on how much current the motor draws. At 60mA you would need (18V-12V)/0.06A = 100Ω, but at 300mA you would need (18V-12V)/0.3A = 20Ω.

If you use a 100Ω resistor then the motor will get the correct voltage at 60mA so it won't over-speed, but under load it will slow down as current increases and the voltage drops. The maximum current it can draw is less than 18V/100Ω = 180mA (less because the motor has *internal* resistance which further limits current) at which point it will be stalled.

Since torque is proportional to current the series resistor also limits maximum torque. However this is not necessarily bad, since it helps protect the motor from burning out or damaging the drive system when overloaded. If you don't mind the motor slowing down under load and don't need full torque then a 100Ω resistor might be OK.

Using a 20Ω resistor the motor would get the correct voltage when fully loaded, but higher voltage when the load is reduced. at no load the 20Ω resistor would only drop 20*0.06 = 1.2V, so the motor would get 18-1.2 = 16.8V which would make it spin 40% faster than normal. This high speed might cause it to throw a winding and/or damage the commutator and brushes.

To reduce the voltage variation you could configure two resistors as a voltage divider. The lower shunt resistor (R2 in the circuit below)  helps to hold the voltage down under light load, and permits a lower value for the upper series resistor (R1) which reduces voltage drop under heavy load. The down-side of this arrangement is higher current draw from the power supply and more power lost in the resistors.

With the resistor values shown motor voltage varies from ~13V at 60mA to 10V at 300mA. Power supply current varies from 260mA to 450mA. R1 and R2 dissipate up to 2.6W and 3.6W respectively, so they should be wirewound types rated at 5W or higher.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdmMmG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To get better regulation you need a device which drops relatively constant voltage no matter how much current the motor draws. A series string of LEDs or diodes would do the job, but only if rated to handle the maximum possible current draw. Standard LEDs are only rated for 20-30mA so they wouldn't survive, but rectifier diodes such as the 1N4001 (rated for 1A) would work. Silicon diodes drop around 0.6-08.V depending on current draw. You want to drop 6V, so you would need 8-10 diodes in series.

Alternatively you could use a Zener diode. The nearest standard value is 5.6V, and 5.6V * 0.3A = 1.7W, so a 3W Zener such as the 1N5919B should do the job (unless this is classed as a 'voltage regulator' and therefore not permitted!)